# For what values $A >0$ do we get subsequences of $y_{n} = \text{ctg}(Aa_{n})$ that do not converge to $0$ when $n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Let $y_{n} = \text{ctg}(Aa_{n})$, where $a_{n} = 2n\pi + o(1)$ and $A > 0$.

- **Question:** For what values $A >0$ do we get subsequences of $y_{n}$
  that do not converge to $0$ when $n \to \infty$?

Well,
$
\text{ctg}(Aa_{n}) = \dfrac{\cos(A a_{n})}{\sin(Aa_{n})}
$, and if $A \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $A \neq 0$, we get $\cos(A a_{n}) = \cos(o(1)) \simeq 1$ and $\sin(A a_{n}) = \sin(o(1)) \simeq 0$, then $\text{ctg}(Aa_{n}) \simeq n$, when $n \to \infty$

Therefore, in my view, it would have to take a non-zero integer $A$. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't. You found some solutions, not all.

Comment: The question seems more like the following. Suppose there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\cot (Aa_n)| \geqslant \delta$ for infinitely many $n$. What can be said about $A$?